# Scope with "WHERE ... LIKE" on a related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get data from a Postgresql table (`table1`) filtered by a field (`property`) of an other related table (`table2`).

In pure SQL I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(table2_id) WHERE table2.property LIKE 'query%'
```

This is working fine:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(query) { includes(:table2).where("table2.property": query) }
```

But what I really need is to filter with a LIKE operator rather than strict equality. However this is not working:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(query) { includes(:table2).where("table2.property LIKE ?", "#{query}%") }
```

As I am getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "table2" LINE 1: ...ble2" WHERE "table1"."user_id" = $1 AND (tabl... ^ : SELECT "table1".* FROM "table1" WHERE "table1"."user_id" = $1 AND (table2.property LIKE 'query%') ORDER BY last_used_at DESC
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, in SQL you'd write `table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table2.property LIKE table1.otherproperty)` so ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.includes()` usually runs 2 separate queries unless it can find that your conditions forces a single `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query, but it fails to do so in your case as the references are in a string (see [this example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)).

You can force the single query behaviour by specifing `.references(:table2)`:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(query) { includes(:table2)
                               .references(:table2)
                               .where("table2.property LIKE ?", "#{query}%") }
```

Or you can you can just use `.eager_load()`:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(query) { eager_load(:table2)
                               .where("table2.property LIKE ?", "#{query}%") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way, By adding `[]` in query.

```
scope :my_scope, ->(query) { includes(:table2).where(["table2.property LIKE (?)", "#{query}%"]) }
```

Also try by adding `(?)`.

Comment: No problem. Keep trying.